# Smoother transitions of other elements on a .fadeOut

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, transition

I'm using jQuery `.fadeOut` to switch between a "cluttered" view and a "minimalist" view.

When you hit the button "view view" it removes a lot of the cluttered information so you can focus on the video (which will be playing in the background, currently turned off).

My problem is that the remaining elements stay put and then when the other elements have fully faded away, they "jump" up which looks kinda ugly.

Is there a way to make those existing elements transition to their new positions gracefully rather than just "jump"?

Please see this site and toggle between "info view" and "video view"
http://fh80.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/fyp/

Here is the code:

```
<script>
/* Video view */

// With the element initially shown, we can hide it slowly:
$( ".switchViewHide" ).click(function() {
    $( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeOut("slow");
    $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow");
    // $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow"); // duplicate
    $("#videoControls p").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#pageControls div.switchViewHide").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#pageControls div.switchViewShow").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#countdownBar").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#grid").fadeOut("slow");
    $("body").addClass('videoView')
});

/* Info view */

// With the element initially shown, we can hide it slowly:
$( ".switchViewShow" ).click(function() {
  $( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeIn( "slow");
  $(".topControls h3").fadeIn("slow");
  $(".topControls h3").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#videoControls p").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#countdownBar").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#grid").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#pageControls div.switchViewHide").fadeIn("slow");
  $("#pageControls div.switchViewShow").fadeOut("slow");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't have .wrapper-dropdown-1 and .loginbox ease in/change their position upwards and downwards respectively when the rest of the transformations occur? E.g. for upwards(in minimal view) it would be something like:

```
$( ".switchViewShow" ).click(function() {
......(other existing code).....
$('.wrapper-dropdown-1, .loginbox').animate({
      top: '-=120'
    }, 1000);
}
```